# United States as first value in alphabetical table

Tags: sql-server

I have a drop down list that is pulling alphabetical country data from a database table. I want the United States to be the first value in the drop down list just under the default "Select One" value. The table columns are (country_cd, country_name), pretty simple.

Would it be easier to edit this in the database, or in the website code? I figure it would be easiest to just move United States to the top of the list in SQL Server, but I cannot find an example on how to move rows up or down in a column on the internet.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will sort the list as you want it:

```
  select country 
    from countries 
order by case when country = 'United States' 
              then '0' 
              else country end;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad717/1/0)